# wx.CollapsiblePane in a wx.Notebook resizing

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to create a wx.CollapsiblePane on a wx.Notebook page which is successfully done using the minimal code example below. However, when the pane is unfolded, the frame fails to resize. However, if instead of creating a Notebook I make a simple Panel (see the commented line in the code), the frame does resize as expected. Any ideas why it doesn't work on a Notebook?

EDIT: I had a chance to test it on Windows and it works (wx 3.0.0.0 and 2.8). There only seems to be a problem in Linux (Ubuntu 13.10 with wx 2.8.12.1).

```py
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):    
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)       

        # Notebook setup 
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.panel)
        #self.nb = wx.Panel(self.panel)  # uncomment this for a working example
        self.pagepanel = wx.Panel(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(self.pagepanel, 'page')

        # add something to the Notebook page
        checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self.pagepanel, -1, 'box 1')

        # add CollapsiblePane to the Notebook page
        colpane = wx.CollapsiblePane(self.pagepanel)  
        colpane.Bind(wx.EVT_COLLAPSIBLEPANE_CHANGED, self.OnPaneChanged)

        # add something to the CollapsiblePane       
        win = colpane.GetPane()        
        checkbox2 = wx.CheckBox(win, -1, 'box 2')

        # Set CollapsiblePane sizer
        colpanesizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)               
        colpanesizer.Add(checkbox2, -1)    
        win.SetSizer(colpanesizer)        
        colpanesizer.SetSizeHints(win)
        colpane.Collapse()        

        # set Notebook page sizer
        pagesizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pagesizer.Add(checkbox)    
        pagesizer.Add(colpane)            
        self.pagepanel.SetSizerAndFit(pagesizer)        

        # set the whole Panel sizer
        panelsizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        panelsizer.Add(self.nb)
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(panelsizer)

        # set Frame size
        self.Fit()

    def OnPaneChanged(self, event):
        # redo the layout        
        self.pagepanel.Layout()
        self.pagepanel.Fit()        
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.panel.Fit()        
        self.Fit()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`colpanesizer.Add(checkbox2, -1)` should be `colpanesizer.Add(checkbox2)`

Try:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # Notebook setup 
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.panel)
        #self.nb = wx.Panel(self.panel)  # uncomment this for a working example
        self.pagepanel = wx.Panel(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(self.pagepanel, 'page')

        # add something to the Notebook page
        checkbox = wx.CheckBox(self.pagepanel, -1, 'box 1')

        # add CollapsiblePane to the Notebook page
        colpane = wx.CollapsiblePane(self.pagepanel)
        colpane.Bind(wx.EVT_COLLAPSIBLEPANE_CHANGED, self.OnPaneChanged)

        # add something to the CollapsiblePane       
        win = colpane.GetPane()
        checkbox2 = wx.CheckBox(win, -1, 'box 2')

        # Set CollapsiblePane sizer
        colpanesizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        colpanesizer.Add(checkbox2)
        win.SetSizer(colpanesizer)
        colpanesizer.SetSizeHints(win)
        colpane.Collapse()

        # set Notebook page sizer
        pagesizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pagesizer.Add(checkbox)
        pagesizer.Add(colpane)
        self.pagepanel.SetSizerAndFit(pagesizer)

        # set the whole Panel sizer
        panelsizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        panelsizer.Add(self.nb)
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(panelsizer)

        # set Frame size
        self.Fit()

    def OnPaneChanged(self, event):
        # redo the layout        
        self.pagepanel.Layout()
        self.pagepanel.Fit()
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.panel.Fit()
        self.Fit()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense and solves the problem on Windows (wx 3.0.0.0 and wx 2.8.something). But still no luck with Ubuntu 13.10 (wx version 2.8.12.1) for some reason.